# Problem with Fonts in MikTex

Tags: fonts, miktex

somehow my MikTex setup cannot find the font that I need to use anymore.
That is the output that I receive from pdflatex:

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
57805 strings out of 493305
1338018 string characters out of 4888868
3655927 words of memory out of 8000000
60187 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
670341 words of font info for 116 fonts, out of 2000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
73i,18n,96p,2026b,1997s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}{C:/Program Files/M
iKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rm.enc}{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/d
vips/lm/lm-mathit.enc}{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathex
.enc}{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathsy.enc}{C:/Program 
Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ts1.enc}{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
ts/enc/dvips/tex-gyre/q-ec.enc}<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/
lm/lmbx10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmex10.pfb><C:
/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi10.pfb><C:/Program Files/Mi
KTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi6.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/typ
e1/public/lm/lmmi8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10
.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr17.pfb><C:/Program F
iles/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr6.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
ts/type1/public/lm/lmr8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/
lmri10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmro10.pfb><C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmro8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmro9.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/p
ublic/lm/lmss12.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmssbx10
.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmsy10.pfb><C:/Program 
Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmsy8.pfb>
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file qagb.pfb.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file f
or reading
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have already several commands to update the fndb, the fontmap and so on.

```
initexmfs --mkmaps
updmap
```

I tried to use the CLI and the GUI of MikTex, but it seems like nothing is working.

It also seems weird to me that MikTex seems to be searching for "qagb.pfb.pfb", the filetype should only be there once, shouldn't it?

Comment: See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/37

Comment: Thank you for the help. How long will it take until there is an update? Would it make sense to edit the map file locally as a work around?

Comment: I guess it will be with you tomorrow or the day after that. Maybe you can edit the maps (I wouldn't know how to do it). I would just use a different font in the meantime (if you don't have a deadline tomorrow morning that is).

Comment: Ok thanks, I will just use another font until tomorrow.

Comment: The problem should be fixed with the update from this morning. In a few tests I just run the TeX Gyre fonts worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the error you can see that pdflatex couldn't load the font:

```
pdflatex.exe (file qagf.pfb.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file f
or reading
```

The font name is **qagf**

Fonts configuration are in cls file. Look for it and make the following change:

```
node[white] {{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \tiny ID}};
```

==>

```
node[white] {{\fontfamily{qagf}\selectfont \tiny ID}};
```

That works for me. It seems that somebody forgot the "f".

Comment: I have already found the error, the problem was that the package in the miktex repository had a bug. The package searched for the file qagf.pfb.pfb even though the file was named qagf.pfb so the file extension was in there twice and it couldn't find it. I think the letter at the end of the file is just to define whether the font is bold, italic, et cetera.